# Is English converging or diverging in modern times?

Tags: dialects, linguistics

For the entire history of the world, languages in disparate groups of people have tended to diverge, creating new languages.  The many English dialects of today would likely have become different languages under the normal progression of history.

But modern times have thrown a wrench into this.  Modern travel and immigration have meant that we often meet speakers of another English dialect in daily life.  Movies and television assist a lot in this as well - mostly Hollywood spreading Americanisms, but there is plenty of British media spreading as well.  The internet means that I can post this and any English speaker can read it.

Has this all meant that English is converging, or are they still diverging?

Comment: This sounds like a good topic for a research project, it's probably not something someone can answer here.

Comment: I agree with Barmar. It is a very interesting subject but one that would not lead to a definite answer (as is required by EL&U.) With regret, I am voting to close it.